# How to properly gender the word "Nutzer"?

Tags: gender, political-correctness, business-correspondence

For men:

> Ticket wird auf Wunsch **des Nutzers** geschlossen.

For women?!

Comment: *Before you answer or comment on this question, please read [our guidelines for questions on gender-neutral language and similar](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you explicitly mean a woman, then it is

> Das Ticket wird auf Wunsch **der Nutzerin** geschlossen.

However, if you want a generic term (that applies for both) then see Takkats comment above, because writing gender-neutral expressions is a topic that is higly disputed in german. Several variants exist, but for different (mostly political) reasons, none of them will make everybody happy.

Answer (score 3):

The German language is capable of compound words.

Therefore I suggest to rephrase

> Ticket wird auf Wunsch des Nutzers geschlossen.

into

> Ticket wird auf Nutzerwunsch geschlossen.

It is *der Wunsch* now and *Wunsch* is not to be gendered. One may object that there still remains the *"Nutzer"* in that word?

[*Geschickt gendern*](https://geschicktgendern.de) suggests to replace

> *Benutzer* –– Anwendende; Nutzende,
>   *Nutzer* –– (be-)nutzende Person; Person, die ... nutzt (sg) and Personen, die ... nutzen; Nutzung; Mitglieder; Nutzende (pl)

Therefore the slightly awkward

> Ticket wird auf Nutzendenwunsch geschlossen. / Ticket wird auf Wunsch der Nutzenden geschlossen.

Easiest would of course be to avoid all of that and not to gender at all, with

> Ticket wurde wunschgemäß (auf Wunsch) geschlossen.

If it is intended for *Behördendeutsch*:

> Ticket wurde auf Antrag der ihn erstellenden Person geschlossen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, whether you want a gender-neutral approach, or just the feminine form of *Nutzer*.

 If the latter is the case, you can use the answer of @PMF.

With issues regarding gender-neutral language, there are often 2 options:

- Visualization of the female gender
- Neutralisation of the gender

Regarding the first point, a construction as seen below is possible:

> Das Ticket wird auf Wunsch des Nutzers/der Nutzerin geschlossen

Unfortunately, as *Nutzer* is in genitive case, you cannot shorten the end by using a construction like this:

> Das Ticket wird auf Wunsch des/der NutzerIn (bzw. Nutzer/in) geschlossen

The genitive *-s* would be missing.

Regarding neutralisation, a construction as followed could be used:

> 1) Das Ticket wird auf Wunsch des/der Nutzenden geschlossen. 
>   2) Das Ticket wird auf Wunsch der nutzenden Person geschlossen.

If you want to dig deeper into gender-neutral language, there is a ton of guidelines from german universities available.

Comment: ... your gender complications are not my fascinations

(based on a Grace Jones rhyme)

Comment: @RalfJoerres I'm not entirely sure, what you want to express. If you want to say, that these constructions are rather clumsy, I agree. I never said one should use these, or that they are beeing used. It is just an attempt to answer the question according to the guidelines; descriptively showing OP's possibilities.